# Modify entity before stringify as JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm working on a project where i need to replace the "language_id" foreign key in my "client" entity with the language object. I've not the hand on database or model (model is generated from existing database with sequelize-auto)

for example:

```
router.get('/:id', function(request, response) {
  models.insurance_client.find({
    where: {
      ID_Insurance_Client: request.params.id
    }
  }).then(function(client) {
    models.def_language.find({
      where:{
        ID_Language: client.relID_Language
      }
    }).then(function(language) {
      client.language = language
      delete client['relID_Language']
      response.send(JSON.stringify(client))
    })
  });
});
```

Here, i want delete the relID_Language field and replace by a language field who will contain the language.

But when i stringify my client, in the json String, relID_Language is still present, and language field doesnt exist. 
(but if i ask to print client.language in console, it's work ! )

How can i modify my Client before parse it in JSON, add the language field with all language values and remove relID_Language field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding raw attribute with true value:

```
where: {
    ID_Insurance_Client: request.params.id
}, raw: true
```